# FirebaseData not loading getting bank screen in fragment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-tablayout, android-recyclerview

**LINK TO GITHUB REPO**
https://github.com/shenoyabhijith/Notifyme2

*here i want to connect it to firebase database and load data into fragments*

**NOTE IM USING FIREBASEUI**

*Custom recyclerAdapter*

*i have 3 fragment* **i want to load different data in all 3 fragment**
*for example i have one fragment from  tablayout*

**when i click on the fragment is empty and get a blank screen**

here  i want to load data from firebaseDatabase
                    **CompanyFragment.java**

```
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
            import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
            import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;

            import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
            import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
            import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

            /**
             * Created by USER on 4/8/2017.
             */

            public class CompanyFragment extends Fragment {

             public CompanyFragment() {
              // Required empty public constructor
             }

             @Override
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             }

             @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              // Inflate the layout for this fragment
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
              DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
              RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);


              FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < Company, ChatHolder > mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < Company, ChatHolder > (
               Company.class,
               android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
               ChatHolder.class,
               databaseReference
              ) {


               @Override
               protected void populateViewHolder(ChatHolder viewHolder, Company model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setCompanyName(Company.getmCompanyName());
                viewHolder.setCompanyPackage(Company.getmCompanyPackage());
               }
              };

              rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);


              rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
              LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
              rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

              return rootView;
             }


            }
```

*class for firebaseRecycler adapter to store and retreive data using getter and setter*

**Company.java**

```
            public class Company {
             private static String mCompanyName;
             private static String mCompanyDescription;
             private static String mCompanyPackage;

             public Company() {

             }

             public Company(String CompanyName, String CompanyDescription, String CompanyPackage) {

              mCompanyName = CompanyName;
              mCompanyDescription = CompanyDescription;
              mCompanyPackage = CompanyPackage;


             }



             public static String getmCompanyName() {
              return mCompanyName;
             }

             public void setmCompanyName(String mCompanyName) {
              this.mCompanyName = mCompanyName;
             }

             public String getmCompanyDescription() {
              return mCompanyDescription;
             }

             public void setmCompanyDescription(String mCompanyDescription) {
              this.mCompanyDescription = mCompanyDescription;
             }

             public static String getmCompanyPackage() {
              return mCompanyPackage;
             }

             public void setmCompanyPackage(String mCompanyPackage) {
              this.mCompanyPackage = mCompanyPackage;
             }
            }
```

**ViewHolder class for firebaseRecyclerAdapter**

```
            public class ChatHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
             private final TextView mNameField;
             private final TextView mTextField;
             public ChatHolder(View itemView) {
              super(itemView);
              mNameField = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_blah);
              mTextField = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
             }
             public void setCompanyName(String CompanyName) {
              mNameField.setText(CompanyName);

             }
             public void setCompanyPackage(String CompanyPackage) {
              mTextField.setText(CompanyPackage);
             }

            }
```

Comment: **here this fragment appears to be blank**

Comment: **NOTE** _HERE IS A LINK TO GITHUBREPO_  https://github.com/shenoyabhijith/Notifyme2

Answer (score 0):

try to set layout manager before setAdapter. While adapter creating the view, adapter doesn't know the Layout manager. That's why u see nothing